# How to I delete a ListTile in its own stateful widget from a list in another stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have built a ListView.builder() in lets call it StatefulWidget1 as seen below that is as long as the index of the List listTile is:

StatefulWidget1 below:

```
ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: listTile.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            // CUSTOM WIDGET
                            return CustomTile(
                                custom: listTile.reversed.toList()[index]);
                          },
                        )
```

CustomTile contains a ListTile() in StatefulWidget2 and I want to be able to have an onPressed event inside of the ListTile() that calls a function in StatefulWidget1 that will delete the CustomTile from the screen and remove itself from the List listTile index.

How do I call a function from StatefulWidget1 inside of StatefulWidget2?
and How do I ensure that I'm deleting the CustomTile of the correct index?

Edit:
or is there another way to delete the CustomTile with the leading: onPressed() {}

StatefulWidget2 Below:

```
Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            '${widget.produce.name} - \$${widget.produce.tilePrice}',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          subtitle: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 3.0),
            child: Text(
                'Weight: ${widget.produce.weight} lbs,\nPrice per lb: \$${widget.produce.pricePerLb}'),
          ),
          trailing: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'edit',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[600]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create a function in your `StatefulWidget1` just like this

```
void _removetile(int index){

   setState(() {
     listTile.reversed.toList().removeAt(index);
   });
}
```

Send this function as argument in your `StatefulWidget2` just like

```
CustomTile(custom: listTile.reversed.toList()[index], removeFunct : 
_removetile, index: index)
```

declar in your customTile just like this

```
class CustomTile extends StatefulWidget{
  final List<YorList> custom;
  final void Function removeFunc;
  final int index;
  CustomTile(this.custom,this.removeFunc,this.index);
}
```

use this function in your leading button just like

```
 leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
        widget.removeFunc(widget.index);
  },
```

Comment: Well laid out explanation, and this works with listTile. removeAt(index) (although deletes the wrong index), however listTile.reversed.toList().removeAt(index) doesn't do anything.  So either I need to figure out another way to delete the proper index, or reverse the list in another way... Any thoughts?

Comment: I fixed this issue by instead of calling listTile.add() and then later reversing the list... I changed it to listTile.insert() and inserted the newest item in the 0 index.  Now everything works great.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
 ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: listTile.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            // CUSTOM WIDGET
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  listTile.remove(index);
                                });
                              },
                              child: CustomTile(
                                custom: listTile.reversed.toList()[index]),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't do a great job of describing what I'm trying to do.  I edited my question to show the 2nd stateful widget that populates the ListView.  I want to call from the second widget to delete itself from the ListView in the first widget.